# Regular expression issue when match a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am **very, very n00b** in regular expression, I'm trying to learn but no success :).

So I have the following file name:  `myFile.8.9.6-x64.txt` or `myFile.8.9.6-x86.txt`

So, I want to create a regular expression in order to match `x64` or `x86` string in file name with:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/[x_X][8][6]|[x][6][4]$/);

console.log(regexp.test("myFile.8.9.6-x64.txt")); //returns false instead of true
```

So, where is my mistake ?

Comment: Remove the `$` from your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use this regex:

```
var regexp = /x(?:86|64)\./i;
```

- `new RegExp` takes a string actually not a regex with delimiters as shown in your question
- You regex has `$` after `64/86` but your file names are not ending with `64/86`.
- No need to repeat `x`
- You can use `/i` for ignore case matching

Comment: I put `$` at end of regex so that was the mistake. Anyway, I will accept this answer.